# SQL or Firebase for Android application

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, rdbms

it's my first post on Stack and i need to have a database to store some information in a server and i don't know what is the best approach to use, i have the choice beetween SQL DB and Firebase. which one will you advice me? keep in mind that maybe i gonna need to send some request like "SELECT * FROM s INNER JOIN s1 WHERE c.."

thanks

Comment: SQL is a programming language used to query relational databases. There are dozens of different implementations of relational databases, each having certain advantages and disadvantages. Not to mention a comparison to a no-sql product. Even if new your requirements fully, there would be lot of debate which one is suitable for you. Since we do not know your requirements, it is impossible to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[look at this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

[and look at this too](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)

The Firebase database does not have the equivalent of SQL's WHERE id IN (1,2,3). In the case of selecting by ID, Firebase's way of retrieving items is equally fast.
In Firebase you must write little bit hard code. And you will get and send data in realTime.

But in SQL if you are not using sockets or etc. you must make call to get data.

For your case , as I see you are beginner, use simple SQL database. Loopj or Volley library. Make practices with JSON. 
Hope I helped you.

Comment: Yes i'm a beginner and gonna use simple SQL db, thanks for you answer!